# Retrieving data from DB in C# to Angular

Tags: c#, angular

I need to Retrieving out for example all the volunteers from the DB
I wrote the service that gets all the volunteers

this is the service:

```
GetAllVolunteers():Observable<Volunteer>{
    return this.http.get<Volunteer>(environment.url+"ward/GetAllVolunteers")
  }
```

here I'm trying to retrieve out the data:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Volunteer } from 'src/app/shared/models/volunteers.models';
import { VolunteerService } from 'src/app/shared/services/volunteer.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-all-volunteers',
  templateUrl: './all-volunteers.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./all-volunteers.component.css']
})
export class AllVolunteersComponent implements OnInit {
  allVolunteers: Array<Volunteer> = [];
  constructor(public volunteerService: VolunteerService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.volunteerService.GetAllVolunteers().subscribe(
      res => {
        this.allVolunteers=res
      }
    )
  }
}
```

this is the function in c# that retrieve all the volunteer:

```
[Route("GetAllVolunteers")]
        public List<volunteerDTO> GetAllVolunteers()
        {
         return volunteerBL.getAllVolunteers().Select(v => BL.converts.volunteersConvert.convertVolunteerToDTO(v)).ToList(); ;
        }
```

How do I place the result in the array allVolunteers[]?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What part doesn't work? It seems fine except a missing semicolon after `this.allVolunteers=res`

Comment: I put a semicolon and it's still wrong

Comment: this is the error:
Type 'Volunteer' is missing the following properties from type 'Volunteer[]': length, pop,push, concat, and 28 more.ts(2740)

Comment: You should use the get function using Volunteer[] instead of Volunteer as a generic type.

Comment: What a get function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your C# api controller action is returning a List of objects :

```
[Route("GetAllVolunteers")]
public List<volunteerDTO> GetAllVolunteers()
{
    return volunteerBL.getAllVolunteers().Select(v => BL.converts.volunteersConvert.convertVolunteerToDTO(v)).ToList(); ;
}
```

But your service function is expecting a single object :

```
GetAllVolunteers():Observable<Volunteer>{
    return this.http.get<Volunteer>(environment.url+"ward/GetAllVolunteers")
}
```

It should expect an array instead :

```
GetAllVolunteers():Observable<Volunteer[]>{
    return this.http.get<Volunteer[]>(environment.url+"ward/GetAllVolunteers")
}
```